# Enable sticky option (Bones theme/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I enable 'Stick this post to the home page' option in Wordpress using the [bones theme](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones) > custom post type... Within the custom-post-type.php file there is this:

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'sticky')
```

it states 'sticky' as an option but it's not supported / documented on the [codex docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Custom Posts and Sticky aren't supported (without writing / installing a plugin).. from what I've read.